# Select variable name for use in a file path powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, automation

I have the variable $ex. It is a list of names with an id, so they are two columns inside. It is of the following format:

```
id,name
-1 app1
 1 app2
 2 app3
 3 app4
```

I want to put the variable name, ex, in a file path that I use to export the said file as csv.

```
$ex
$path="C:\Users\Local\'$ex'.csv"
Out-File -FilePath $path  -InputObject $ex
```

The error I am getting is

```
Out-File : Illegal characters in path.
```

The ideal outcome would be the csv to be exported and have the name ex. In case of a different name, to have the said name.

The path would look like this

```
$path="C:\Users\Local\$ex.csv"
```

the output would be ex.csv, that is, the name of the variable as the name of the csv.

if the file name is $new_file, the output of the csv should be new_file.csv

Comment: I am doing this and instead of the name being the name of the csv, for instance, ex.csv, I am getting path="C:\Users\Local\id,name
-1,app1
1,app2   which is the content of the csv file. The file is not deposited anywhere and getting the same error message as above

Comment: I did that thanks.

Comment: "*The path would look like this `$path="C:\Users\Local\$ex.csv`*"??? What is the literal path you expecting?  I suspect that you actually want to create multiple `csv` files (with a single entry? what do you expect to be in the file?) but that isn't clear in the question either...

Comment: In the csv file, I expect the the ex values would be there. So, there would be the id,name with their values in it. So my variable is named here $ex. I want to deposit the file in the directory with the out-file command. The csv name would be ex.csv and the values in this csv would be the id,name columns with their values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251789/discussion-between-almosino-and-iron).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$path="C:\Users\Local\$($ex).csv"
```